# Magento 2 equivalent event of checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

I am working In Magento 2 Module, I've to do some customization on Magento Onepage checkout, for that I plan to use the **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**, but In my project, We're installed some third-party modules, which are already used this event.

**So, I believe if I again use the same event It won't work, an observer doesn't have an order to execute.**

**I want the equivalent event of `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`. Is there have anything in Magento 2 Kindly let me know it.**

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not have any event equivalent to `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

One solution you can try to make a different module for different Observer.

And Make one module depends on another.

**Let's give an example:**

- `ModuleA:` Observer class `ObserverClassA`.
- `ModuleB:` Observer Class `ObserverClassB`.

Assume that `ObserverClassB` need to run after `ObserverClassA` .

So, please make  `ModuleB` is module depend on `ModuleA`.

Add  `sequence` on `ModuleB`'s `module.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ModuleB" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="ModuleA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**After that don't forgot run setup upgrade to apply these changes.**

I guess that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Magento has the event (checkout_onepage_controller_success_action) check the below https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-events/

Comment: What you mean Sorry Don't understand. I don't say the event does not exist.

Comment: I guess that your issue at your observers code.Please share the code of two observers.

Comment: Magento 2 3 core module are used same events. `vendor/magento/module-google-adwords/etc/frontend/events.xml,vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/etc/frontend/events.xml,vendor/magento/module-signifyd/etc/events.xml`